# Would this be the correct approach for solving y'' - 4y = 4H(t-2)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

If not, what would be a better way?

Please see attached image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1sj5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You get from the general setup of such tasks $y(t)=0$ for $t<0$, which includes $y'(0)=0$. In consequence also $y(t)=0$, $y'(t)=0$ for $t<2$. For $t>2$ the equation reads
$$
y''-4y=4,~~y(2)=0,~~y'(2)=0
$$
with a solution
$$
y(t)+1=A\sinh(2(t-2))+B\cosh(2(t-2)),
$$
so that $B=1$ and $A=0$. In total
$$
y(t)=H(t-2)(\cosh(2(t-2))-1)=2H(t-2)\sinh^2(t-2).
$$

---

Please explain, in typed text, not another image, where the contemplation of the Laplace transform of $tf(t)$ for the treatment of the right side comes from.